# Setting OnCheckedChangeListener with a Lambda

Tags: java, android, lambda

I want to use a lambda rather than an anonymous class for OnCheckedChangeListener.

The original code for setting the listener works fine and reads:

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
    }
});
```

I tried changing it to a lambda by doing:

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(l -> mCrime.setSolved(isChecked));
```

but I receive an error from Android Studio saying: cannot resolve symbol is checked.

I had thought a lambda would resolve isChecked implicitly even though the onCheckChanged takes two arguments. What is wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. What you have shouldn't even compile. Use this:

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((view, isChecked) -> mCrime.setSolved(isChecked));
```

The stuff before the `->` doesn't represent the listener, but rather the arguments that are passed in that listener, in this case a View and a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

isChecked is just a parameter name it is not there when you are using lambdas how ever here is the correct lambda with the parameter names for your onCheckChangeListener

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) (buttonView, isChecked) -> mCrime.setSolved(isChecked));
```

Answer (score 0):

`setOnCheckedChangeListener` has two parameters

`CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked`, so the lambda statement would be

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(buttonView, isChecked -> mCrime.setSolved(isChecked))
```

That being said, I'm not familiar enough with Java lambdas to know if it can handle multiple params.

Comment: Only if it is in parentheses